# Почему Tomcat обращается к index.jsp, а не к Hello_world.html?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, eclipse

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать Spring MVC приложение из курса https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgE5DoIN6Bs&list=PLAma_mKffTOR5o0WNHnY0mTjKxnCgSXrZ&index=15

Для начала скажу, что не смог найти в интернете, как подключить сервер Tomcat к Idea Community Edition, поэтому скачал Eclipse и стал делать проект в нем.

Сервер установил, сделал все по видео, все везде вроде верно указано, но когда создается сервер, то он берет информацию из начального файла index.jsp, а не из Hello_world.html, созданного мной.

Прикрепляю архитектуру проекта:[image: Архитектура проекта]

**код HelloController.java**

```
package ru.vicero13.homeprojects;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

**код Hello_world.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My app</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello world!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**код applicationContextMVC.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.vicero13.homeprojects"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**код web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>TestSpringMVC</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering/>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Что я делаю не так? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat по default на старте обращается к странице index которая неявно у вас указана в web.xml, что бы изменить стартовую страницу нужно.

Задекларировать в web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

И добавить mapping

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/hello-world", "/"})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По стартовой странице понятно. Но мне нужно, чтобы любые файлы html, которые я создаю вызывались, когда я ввожу в адресной строке запрос. Например, тут у меня в @GetMapping("/hello-world"). Соответственно, должна открываться страница hello_world.html Там есть для этого метод и все везде вроде бы правильно завязано, но не работает и при вводе в строку поиска данного запроса выдает 404 ошибку...

Answer (score 0):

Заходите в настройки вашего томката -> Deployment -> внизу в Application context ставите "/". И уже потом перезагружаете сервер и переходите по маппингам

Comment: "настройки вашего томката" - не смог найти...

Comment: к сожалению, я работаю в intellij idea, поэтому ничем не могу помочь.

Comment: в communtity edition или ultimate?

Comment: по-идее - в любой

Comment: в community edition просто нельзя сбилдить проект на томкат сервере как я понял. Поэтому спросил, ведь если Вы тоже работаете в community, то может подскажете, как это сделать.

Comment: нет, я в ultimate работаю